# Is the fetchval in asyncpg safly for sql injections?

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

Is the fetchval in asyncpg safly for sql injections?

https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=fetch#asyncpg.connection.Connection.fetch

```
async def get_user_id_by_bot_id(self, bot_id):
        record: Record = await self.pool.fetchval(self.GET_USER_ID_BY_BOT_ID, (bot_id))
        print(record)
        return record
```

Thank You for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, asyncpg uses PostgreSQL's syntax for parameter substitution. As long as you use that feature, by passing the arguments and using `$` followed by the index of the argument, you should be safe!

You shouldn't put the args in a tuple like you show in your code, but do this:

```py
record: Record = await self.pool.fetchval(self.GET_USER_ID_BY_BOT_ID, bot_id)
```

Some more examples of how you should correctly use parameter substitution:

```py
record = await self.pool.fetchval("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1;", my_id)
```

```py
record = await self.pool.fetchval("UPDATE table SET name = $1 WHERE id = $2 AND username = $3;", new_name, my_id, username)
```